# Angular 2 Twitter login

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to login users to my app via Twitter in **angular2 + typescript**. I couldn't find any examples and I'm really stuck with it. I managed to get Facebook and Google login but not Twitter. Can you show me an example how's doing that? Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: First you need to register and get the api keys .and install twitter plugin .Try this `https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-twitter`

Comment: @georgeawg may be OP does not have clear idea about `tags` .but look he is trying angular 2.

Comment: Have got any way to do twitter login ?

Comment: did you find any solution?